# Can I create an SSL cert for a server that doesn't exist yet?

Tags: ssl, https, certificate, ssl-certificate, system-administration

Someone just asked me to create an SSL certificate for a server that hasn't been created yet.

In fact, it's going to be hosted, so I won't even have a linux account to ssh into it.

Normally I would create the CSR on the server, and then send it to a registrar like Thawte.

Does this request make sense ?  Is it possible to create an SSL cert without having ssh access to a server ?  Or is my boss not understanding the process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For web server running over https protocol, the important component of SSL certificate is the subject's CN field. This field is matched by browser against the DNS record to verify the web server is indeed whoever it claimed to be

[image]

You can purchase a SSL certificate without physically provisioning the server. However as part of purchase procedure the CA will perform domain ownership verification (and more rigorous vetting if you purchase OV/EV certs)

It doesn't matter where (physically) the command to generate private key and issue CSR is executed as long as the final product is installed once the server is provisioned

Furthermore, repointing the DNS record to different server doesn't require new cert to be issued. The important thing is you decide on DNS entry name.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can create the CSR (PKCS10) on a different server than the one you install the certificate on. Just make sure you get the whole pfx back, with both the private and public key. However, it will now work if you have a HSM, as the private key will be stored in the HSM, and not be transportable.